# Is Minecraft's source code available?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I recall Mojang stating they would release the source code of Minecraft sooner or later, but searching both on google and on Minecraft sites I wasn't about to find it.

So... is it available somewhere? With what license?

PS: not interested in sources decompiled from the binaries, only in genuinely officially released sources.

Comment: too localized to ask about a particular game source code imo

Comment: @GameDev-er and why should this be too localised? After all, seems like a legit and useful question, to me...

Comment: I'm still clueless about why this has been closed, a comment would help. Seems like both arbitrary and just plain wrong to me.

Comment: It was closed because 5 voting members agreed it was off topic. I voted because I agree with the first comment, the availability of the source code of a single game is too localized for the site. I'm sure you would agree, asking if the source code of Call of Duty was available, or a little game on the Play store that has fewer than 100 downloads. It's a research task that people need to perform for the specific game they're interested in.

Comment: @Byte56 you would have to judge case by case. Notch **did** declare that Minecraft sources would have been released, and I remembered (incorrectly) that already happened. Then, searching for them, I found nothing. That's why I asked here: I did research, what I found (or not found) didn't match what I _knew_, only solution was asking.

Comment: Questions are judged case by case, and this one was closed. If you stand by your assertion that they should be judged case by case, then you shouldn't have a problem with this being closed. In the future, I suggest attempting to contact the developer for the game you're interested in. They're the ones that would have the most correct answer.

Comment: -2, closed... and "accidentally" it still gets 2500 views...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Notch said at some point that he plans to release the sources once the game is no longer selling, but that was WAY before it got this big.

And yes, it's still selling.

Comment: Two of the libraries used, [DataFixerUpper](https://github.com/Mojang/DataFixerUpper) and [Brigadier](https://github.com/Mojang/brigadier), are now available under the MIT License.

Answer (score 7):

I know there's an already accepted answer and it's not quite on the spot - but I also came here via Google and I was looking to learn and thought others might, too.

There are other open-source Minecraft clones (and [InfiniMiner](https://code.google.com/p/infiniminer/source/checkout) which is what Minecraft is based off, too).

I'd suggest anyone who is looking to study up on it looks at these:

- [TechCraft](http://techcraft.codeplex.com/) ([alternate repo](https://github.com/jhorv-scs/TechCraft))
- [InfiniMiner](https://code.google.com/p/infiniminer/source/checkout)
- [ManicDigger](https://github.com/manicdigger/manicdigger)
- [Bukkit](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit) (This is an extension of Minecrafts server system)
- [Bravo](http://www.bravoserver.org/) (This is an open-source Minecraft server re-implementation)

Comment: I guess it answers the question - but I think the OP was looking for a bit more... perhaps to learn from. However, I could be wrong and I guess it answered the OPs question. Feel free to edit my answer if it feels wrong to you, though.

Comment: As I said, was just curious what you meant by that.

Comment: @VaughanHilts thanks. I agree, a perfect answer would have included said links, but I was too lazy to google for them at the time. I seriously didn't expect to get that many upvotes anyway..

Comment: This is nice and informative, and I appreciate that. However, I was looking only for the official source code, so the accepted answer is precise. Thanks anyway, and keep this answer since it might help others!